# grok filter to extract some message from two specific words

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

sample log file is below

```
2018-07-02 09:35:57 991 [INFO] from application in pool-2-thread-9 - Authenticate document processing time for transactionId : 1271400374895007_node1 documentType : Passport is 1629 msec
```

I wrote grok filter to extract some fields like transaction, document type, duration

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]) (?<logger>(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9$]+)\s+(-\s+)? %{GREEDYDATA} .*transactionId : %{WORD:transactionid} documentType : %{WORD:document type} is (?<duration>.*msec
```

can someone please suggest how to extract data between two specific words  "-" (between-message) "processing time"

Comment: can you please clarify what you want to extract? I don't understand what you need to extract

Comment: I want separate message field between "-" and "processing time". because those 2 fields are constant middle of the message will change so often.

Comment: so you need everything between `-` and `processing time`  to be assigned to a new field?

Comment: in your example `Authenticate document` should be assigned to a new field?

Comment: yup , you'r correct.

Comment: can you please check my answer? let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom pattern to match everything between `-` and `processing time`,

```
(?<pool_thread>\w+[-]\d+[-]\w+[-]\d+\s*?)-(?<custom_word>.*?)(processing time)
```

This will output,

```
{
  "pool_thread": [
    [
      "pool-2-thread-9 "
    ]
  ],
  "custom_word": [
    [
      " Authenticate document "
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: perfect it's working and can you please suggest me how to separate number  filed before msec word

Comment: can you match them separately? `%{INT} %{WORD}`

Comment: yes I already did that but i want separate number field before specific keyword  "msec" keyword even though if it comes in middle of log message

Comment: can you give an example what you want?

Comment: i want to separate keyword which is before word "msec" always, no matter where it will be in log message

Comment: you can ignore everything before `msec` using `%{INT}.*%{WORD}` , if this isn't what you are asking, you need to ask a new question and provide a clear example with example input and expected output